# Is there any subtle difference between the words "truthful","honest" and "veracious"?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, british-english

is there any difference between words "truthful","honest" and "veracious"? or do they mean exactly the same?

I checked the dictionaries but want to learn subtlety in their meanings.

Comment: To me "veracious" is a *character trait* with respect to speech, "truthful" is the *description of behavior* with respect to speech, and "honest" has a higher connotation, since it relates to "honor".

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

- Truthful as about the absolute fact: "Truthfully, your chocolate cake tasted oddly of liver."
- Honest is about openness: "Honestly, I hated it."

And one can be truthful without being honest:

> Q: What do you think of my new hat/hair style/dress...
>
> A: It's quite eye-catching.

Regarding veracious... I don't think I've ever seen or heard it used.

Comment: Now this is a BIG problem for non native english speakers like me. How am I to know whether a word is commonly used one or obselete? I mean I came across this word "veracious" somewhere while reading GRE word list. I do not want to learn words that are not even known to the native speakers.